flutter scroll page with Draggable
I have a problem with scroll page ,
I want to when i drag some items , can scroll the page for match item.
i use scrollBar too. but did't work
can anyone help me please?
.
.
.
here is my code :
 
class MatchingQuestion extends StatefulWidget {
  final dynamic itemData;
  const MatchingQuestion({Key? key, required this.itemData}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MatchingQuestion> createState() => _MatchingQuestionState();
}

class _MatchingQuestionState extends State<MatchingQuestion> {
  Map<int, int?> questionToOption = {}; // Maps question index to option index
  final ItemCardResponse itemCardResponse = Get.put(ItemCardResponse());
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> generateMatchedDataList() {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> matchedDataList = [];
    final QuestionNavigationController questionNavigationController = Get.put(QuestionNavigationController(''));

    questionToOption.forEach((questionIndex, optionIndex) {
      if (optionIndex != null) {
        // Ensure there's a match
        Map<String, dynamic> matchedData = {
          'question': widget.itemData.questions[questionIndex].value,
          'option': widget.itemData.options[optionIndex].value,
        };
        matchedDataList.add(matchedData);
      }
    });

    questionNavigationController.answerOfQuestion(matchedDataList, widget.itemData.id, context);
    return matchedDataList;
  }

  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    // itemCardResponse.statusSendAnswer(false);
    super.dispose();
  }

 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(() {
      List<Map<String, dynamic>> matchedDataList = generateMatchedDataList();
      if (itemCardResponse.isSendAnswer.value) {
        itemCardResponse.sendAnswer(
          widget.itemData.id,
          matchedDataList,
          context,
        );
      }
      return SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.w),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 25.w,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: (widget.itemData.questions.length * 80.w),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: widget.itemData.questions.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, questionIndex) {
                    bool isMatched = questionToOption.containsKey(questionIndex);
                    return Draggable<int>(
                      data: questionIndex,
                      feedback: Material(
                          elevation: 0.0,
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.w),
                            child: Container(
                              width: 310.w,
                              height: 62.w,
                              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                              decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                                color: isMatched ? EnvColors.greyBox : EnvColors.pink,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.w),
                                ),
                              ),
                              // color: isMatched ? Colors.grey : Colors.blue[100], // Turn grey if matched
                              child: ListTile(
                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                minVerticalPadding: 0.0,
                                title: Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    widget.itemData.questions[questionIndex].value,
                                    style: AppTextTheme.text14w400white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          )),
                      childWhenDragging: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.w),
                        child: Container(
                          width: 310.w,
                          height: 62.w,
                          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                          decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                            color: Color(0x076C6CFF),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              side: BorderSide(width: 1.50, color: EnvColors.lightPurple),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: ListTile(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            minVerticalPadding: 0.0,
                            title: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                widget.itemData.questions[questionIndex].value,
                                style: TextStyle(color: EnvColors.lightBlue),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: isMatched
                          ? Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.w),
                              child: DottedBorder(
                                borderType: BorderType.RRect,
                                radius: Radius.circular(16.w),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.w),
                                dashPattern: [4, 8],
                                color: EnvColors.greyBorder,
                                child: ListTile(
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                  minVerticalPadding: 0.0,
                                  title: Center(
                                      child: Text(
                                    widget.itemData.questions[questionIndex].value,
                                    style: isMatched ? AppTextTheme.text14w400greyText : AppTextTheme.text14w400white,
                                  )),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          : Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.w),
                              child: Container(
                                width: 292.w,
                                height: 62.w,
                                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                                decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                                  color: isMatched ? EnvColors.greyBox.withOpacity(0.5) : EnvColors.purple,
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.w),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                // color: isMatched ? Colors.grey : Colors.blue[100], // Turn grey if matched
                                child: ListTile(
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                  minVerticalPadding: 0.0,
                                  title: Center(
                                      child: Text(
                                    widget.itemData.questions[questionIndex].value,
                                    style: isMatched ? AppTextTheme.text14w400greyText : AppTextTheme.text14w400white,
                                  )),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: (widget.itemData.options.length * 80.w),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: widget.itemData.options.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, optionIndex) {
                    return DragTarget<int>(
                      onAccept: (receivedQuestionIndex) {
                        setState(() {
                          questionToOption[receivedQuestionIndex] = optionIndex;
                        });
                        // Print the matched question and option
                        print("Question ${widget.itemData.questions[receivedQuestionIndex].value} matched with Option ${widget.itemData.options[optionIndex].value}");
                      },
                      builder: (context, candidateData, rejectedData) {
                        int? matchedQuestionIndex = questionToOption.entries.firstWhere((entry) => entry.value == optionIndex, orElse: () => MapEntry(-1, null)).key;
                        bool isMatched = matchedQuestionIndex != -1;
                        String displayText = isMatched ? widget.itemData.questions[matchedQuestionIndex].value : widget.itemData.options[optionIndex].value;

                        return Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.w),
                          child: Container(
                            width: 292.w,
                            height: 62.w,
                            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                            decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                              color: isMatched ? EnvColors.pink.withOpacity(0.8) : EnvColors.white,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                side: BorderSide(width: 1.50, color: EnvColors.lightPurple),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: ListTile(
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                              minVerticalPadding: 0.0,
                              title: Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                displayText,
                                style: isMatched ? AppTextTheme.text14w400white : AppTextTheme.text14w400greyText,
                              )),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}

when one item selected , page should scroll too,
I tried it with draggable_scrollbar but I hadn't success.
enter image description here
